# Split an array into non-decreasing arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to split a given array into the non-decreasing arrays without for loops or using `np.diff`. I wonder if that could be done with `np.where` but can't imagine how to make it without looping.

Comment: I think you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding exactly what your question is.  Can you define “non-decreasing arrays”—Is it just an array where the values don’t appear in exactly decreasing fashion?  Finally When you use the words cycles are you talking about for or while loops?

Comment: Why are you considering Numpy?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using numpy:

```
def split_increasing(x):
    # Check if following value is greater
    ix = np.greater(a[:-1], a[1:])
    # Use the indices where the above is True
    # to split the array
    return np.split(a, np.flatnonzero(ix)+1)
```

---

Lets check with some random array:

```
a = np.random.randint(1,20,10)
# array([12, 15,  3,  7, 18, 18,  9, 16, 15, 19])
split_increasing(a)
```

**Output**

```
[array([12, 15]), array([ 3,  7, 18, 18]), array([ 9, 16]), array([15, 19])]
```